# Open database for various DB servers

Tags: database

For benchmarking and testing, I am looking for an open SQL database that can be installed in various database servers (e.g. Postgres, MySQL, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good option for RDMS (relational databases, aka SQL) is the [Chinook Database](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database), which is based on an iTunes library.

> Chinook is a sample database available for SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. It can be created by running a single SQL script. Chinook database is an alternative to the Northwind database, being ideal for demos and testing ORM tools targeting single and multiple database servers.
>
> Supported Database Servers
>
> - MySQL
> - SQL Server
> - SQL Server Compact
> - SQLite
> - PostgreSQL
> - Oracle
> - DB2

[Downloads](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database/tree/master/ChinookDatabase/DataSources)

> If you want to use the data from your own iTunes library, then replace the file ChinookDatabase\DataSources_Xml\Source\iTunes Music Library.xml with your version.

Downside seems to be that most scripts are for windows, although the `.sql` database statements can be loaded directly.

License: [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

---

([my source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19640980))